# LAPACK functions

Tags: c++, linux, lapack

I want to run a simple lapacke code which is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   double a[5][3] = {1,1,1,2,3,4,3,5,2,4,2,5,5,4,3};
   double b[5][2] = {-10,-3,12,14,14,12,16,16,18,16};
   lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;
   int i,j;

   m = 5;
   n = 3;
   nrhs = 2;
   lda = 3;
   ldb = 2;

   info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',m,n,nrhs,*a,lda,*b,ldb);

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      for(j=0;j<nrhs;j++)
      {
         printf("%lf ",b[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return(info);
}
```

but I can't , I got the following problem, any help pleas?
I compile using:      icc -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9 ran_matrix.cpp -o ran_mat

```
qarni@c4hdn:~$ icc -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9 ran_matrix.cpp -o ran_mat
ran_matrix.cpp(2): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "lapacke.h"
  #include <lapacke.h>
                      ^

compilation aborted for ran_matrix.cpp (code 4)
```

Comment: Probably the path to lapacke.h is simply not part of your include path. Call icc with an additional -I/path/to/lapacke.

Comment: I tried it but it did not work also, as follows:  icc -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9 ran_matrix.cpp -o  -I/path/to/lapack ran_mat

Comment: do you have `lapack-devel` and `blas-devel` package on your system ?

Comment: mmm I do not know, how can I check that?

Comment: for centos type linux distribution `sudo yum whatprovides lapack-devel`
`sudo yum whatprovides blas-devel` will tell you if the repo is installed 
if not installed : `yum install lapack-devel` and `sudo yum install blas-devel`

Comment: `-o` is for the name of the executable. Could you try `icc ran_matrix.cpp -o ran_mat -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9 -I/yourpathtolapackeh -L/yourpathtoliblapackea/ -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm` ? `-l` signals libraries that you want to link and `-L` provides the directories to explore, just like `-I` for includes.

Comment: yes, I tried it and I got:   #include <lapacke.h>
                      ^

compilation aborted for ran_matrix.cpp (code 4)